# Cache Control headers not doing the JOB

Tags: php, html, browser-cache

I have tried all the headers  i can find in the internet for my webpage not to store the cache, but it doesn't work. I have tried all the php headers, and the HTML meta tags you can ever find.

My webpage only runs smoothly when the " Disable Cache" is ticked under the network tab.

When i look at the cache storage under dev tools there is no data. So i think the headers are actually working, but the data updates  when i manually clear the cache in the browser or when disable cache is ticked.

I dont think i have to do anything on the server side as when clear cache is pressed on the browser, everything runs fine.

NOTE: I have tried all solutions from stack overflow.

This is the last one i tried

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: What problem does your web page have for which disabling the cache is apparently a solution? Perhaps you'll have more luck fixing that.

Comment: its just a JavaScript file that changes the button colour. If you clear the cache just once manually then it works smoothly

Answer (score 1):

### What is Cache?

Cache-Control is an HTTP cache header, Which simply Makes your website Faster, Also it can help your website when using Private Info!!!

### How to see if my website is caching?

Inspect Elements -> Network -> click on the image / file -> Responses Header -> cache-control

### Settings Up cache

For Php

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400');
?>
```

For Apache

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=84600, public"
</filesMatch>
```

For nginx

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 2d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
}
```

### I dont Want Cache

In that case you need to use :

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache')
?>
```

If you dont see This taking effect, first try using it on another browser or removing your cache

### Using Meta Tags

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

### Checking if my Website is cached

#1 - Is cached
[image: A cached Website]
#2 - Is not cached
[image: A none-cached website]

Comment: shouldn't the max age be 0 if i want no cache?

Comment: I updated My post @JTC, And no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate Should Do the Job , BUT why would you want to remove cache?

Comment: hey tried tried all that headers, but its behaving the same way. the reason is that every time i load the webpage the info is loaded from the cache and not from the server. I have a dynamic webpage which shows real time info.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! Can i ask you where are you viewing this. I checked under every tab in developer tools and couldnt find

Comment: its in the Inspect elements->Network Tab And then you need to select a file / img or what ever then you will see such a thing